# How to rename and move files from different directories to one common directory?

Tags: python, file, file-handling

Given the following directory structure:

```
dir/2012-01-01/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-02/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-03/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-04/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-05/employee.csv.bz2
```

I would like to rename the extention from `csv.bz2` to `.csv`  and move only files with `.csv` extensions to a new folder:

```
dir/all_files
```

What I have tried was the following, which renames fine but doesn't move the files to new direction:

```
path = 'dir/'
os.mkdir('dir/all_files')

extensions = ('.csv')
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
       ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()
        if ext in extensions:
           infilename = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
           newname = os.path.join('dir', 'all_files',  filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv'))
           output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

which moves only the first entry and results in the error:

```
output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already   exists: 'dir/2012-01-01\\employee.csv.bz2' -> 'dir/all_files\\employee.csv'
```

It makes sense of course because I want to move files which are all labeled as `employee.csv`.

My question is how can I move these files to `all_files`?

Comment: What is your current working directory? That is, the directory where the Python instance is running? Does all your directories in `dir/` start with `2012-`?

Comment: You need to give them individual names, possibly based on the directory they reside in, because you can't have multiple `employee.csv` files in one dir.

Comment: Hi yes, `dir/` starts with `2012` but may change to `2013` soon :). python is running `/usr/bin/python`and the current working directory is `/home/myname/` when `os.getcwd()` . I have tried to give unique names by appending milliseconds to the `newname` but it still brings the error. I suppose I have to append kind of a sequence. Here my python knowledge ends.

Comment: And by `employee.csv.bz2` you mean `[Tom, Dick, Harry].csv.bz2`, right? Or is it exactly as you state it? In which case, would it be alright if we rename to `Date-employee.csv.bz2` instead, where Date can be 2012-01-01, 2012-01-02, ...?

Comment: Does each directory contain just one `employee.csv.bz2` file?

Comment: It doesnt have to keep its original name. But I have tried to append `millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))` already so that doesnt work either.

Comment: Yes each directory contain just one `employee.csv.bz2`

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, but I think you are right by suggesting to append the correspodning `Date` to `employee.csv.bz2`.  However I dont know how that works :)

Comment: One important question: what is your OS?

Comment: Its `Ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: @HiThere: Solved! Try out my code and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are putting all the files into the same directory and they all have the same name. You could just rename them depending on what their first folder's name was. This code should work:

```
import os

path = 'dir/'
os.mkdir('dir/all_files')

extensions = ['.csv']
for folder, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if folder == path or folder == os.path.join(path, 'all_files'):
            continue
        folder = folder.strip(path)
        extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])[-1].lower()
        if extension in extensions:
            infilename = os.path.join(path, folder, filename)
            newname = os.path.join(path, 'all_files', "{}-{}".format(folder.strip('./'), filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv')))
            os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Comment: Hi Stan, thank you for the soltion. All the files have to be in the same folder. Not sure whether this is the case here

Comment: so what do you want their names to be? probably `2012-01-01-employee.csv` etc.?

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Comment: Hi Stan thats cool thx! However, where does `zip(subfolders, filename):` comes from? `for subfolder, filename in zip(subfolders, filename):
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined`

Comment: my bad it should be `filenames` not `filename`

Comment: Nope not in that form , Im trying to `print (newname)` it gives no error and no output , I suppose there is still something wrong :=)

Comment: @StamKaly: I kind of tried it myself. It didn't work for me. I'm just getting a dummy file in `all_files` with a date prepended to it.

Comment: Hi @StamKaly `print(newname)` returns all files like `B:/dir/all_files\:-employee.csv` and 
`B:/dir/all_files\B-employee.csv.bz2` you last edit doesnt return at all, but also no error :)

Comment: yeah i am working on it should be ok in just a couple of moments

Comment: @StamKaly, one last question. Without the renaming part `filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv')` how would you pass everything to `newname` ?

Comment: replace `filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv')` with `filename`

Answer (score -1):

If everything you stated in the question is true, the following would be a straight forward solution for your problem:

```
import os
import re

path = 'dir/'

# os.mkdir(path+'all_files')
os.system('ls '+path+' > '+path+'dirList.txt');

with open(path+'dirList.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match('[1-9]',line):
            os.system('mv '+path+line.strip()+'/employee.csv.bz2 '
                      +path+'all_files/'+line.strip()+'-employee.csv')

os.system('rm '+path+'dirList.txt') # Optional delete the temporary file
```

I simulated your problem statement and verified the above code and it is **specific to Unix and Linux-based OSs** like Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: adding strings together is bad practice, also there is no point to use linux' terminal since the commands exist in python